# How to disable data for individual apps?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I am using an Android 4.4, and I would like to know how to disable the wifi connection for only certain apps? Is there a third party app out there that can perform this function?

Comment: Is your device rooted? Which device? Phrase add these details

Comment: You can look at this approach and revert if you want a similar solution to your problem http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127892/is-there-a-network-manager-app-with-profiles-to-allow-only-specific-apps-to-use

Answer (score 2):

The exact method will change depending on your version of Android and phone model, but it should be more or less the same.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Data usage` (or `mobile network`) > `Network restrictions` (or `Mobile hotspots`)
2. Turn your WiFi networks into mobile hotspots or metered connections by checking them/moving the sliders.
3. Go back to your `Data Usage` / `Mobile Network` settings page and tap the app you would like to restrict
4. Scroll down and select **Disable background data**

This is more of a workaround, and you will have to set every WiFi network you connect to as a metered connection.

Depending on which phone you use, you may be able to root it and completely stop an app from accessing the internet.

Comment: Nice trick I hadn't thought about – but sounds reasonable. Apart from the drawbacks you've mentioned: wouldn't this affect *background* data only – so as soon as the app is running in foreground, it had access to the network again?

Comment: I did not think about that. Yes, it will have access to the network when this happens. Sorry about that.
The only other way I can think of is to use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to disable WiFi whenever you start up the app, and enable it again once you close the app, although this may be far from ideal.
I haven't tried this [app, but it claims to do what you wanted.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.NetBlocker)

Comment: If you are willing to root, you could give [XPrivacy](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacy-ultimate-android-privacy-app-t2320783) a chance.

Comment: Yupp, on rooted devices that's a good solution not only for network – which brings me to another idea for not-rooted devices …

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Firewall app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377). Depending on whether your device is rooted, your choices might differ – so let me name two of the candidates here:

- [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) certainly is the first choice for rooted devices. Free and open-source, it's also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)
- [NetGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard) would be the pendant for not-rooted devices, also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=eu.faircode.netguard)

[image: AFWall+] [image: NetGuard]

With both you can decide per-app whether it should have access to WiFi, mobile data, both or none.